# CKEditor 4 div around table

Tags: javascript, html, class, html-table, ckeditor4.x

I use the following plugin for CKEditor 4.
https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/table

I would like to put the tables in a div container with a class. Can someone help me with this?

Unfortunately, I do not really know what to do. Could someone be helpful to me? That would be super nice.

Comment:  Please share more about what you've tried, code snippets etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.